# pip install generates WARNINGS : 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at ...>

Tags: python, pip, installation

I have spent a lot of time searching if someone did already have the same issue but I did not find anything.

For some time, I have warnings each time I want to install a package with pip. The installation works at the end but it takes much more time. The warning consists in a repetition of 5 times the same WARNING :

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x105b71c50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused')': /simple/mako/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x105b6c690>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused')': /simple/mako/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x105b6cb90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused')': /simple/mako/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x105bb6f10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused')': /simple/mako/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x105bb67d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused')': /simple/mako/
```

After these warnings, everything seems to work well, but I would like to remove them to speed up the installations.

If you need more information, please don't hesitate to ask, I am not sure where I should dig to solve that so I don't know what kind of information would be needed.

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Hi! Are you using a proxy server?

Comment: Like @isydmr asked, are you behind a proxy?

Could you share the content of your pip.ini file (pip.conf on Linux)?

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file

Comment: Hello @isydmr, thanks for you questions ! I do not have any proxy running. As for my pip.conf file located under ~/.pip/pip.conf (I am on MacOS), it only contains the following lines : 
"""
[global]
extra-index-url = http://localhost:22004/simple
"""

Comment: Check out `internet connection`

Answer (score 9):

For some one who using win10 wsl2 of Ubuntu20 with conda environment:

Please run the following code first out of conda:

```sh
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Then activate any conda environment, the pip install can run successfully.

Comment: Tried this for Debian 11 on windows 10 wsl2. Doesn't work. This is a problem that never existed under Debian 9 or 10 under wsl.

Comment: This fixed my problem on WSL1, Windows 10 (I was using Miniconda).

Comment: First two steps was enough for make it to work. I was also on WSL1, Windows 10 and was using miniconda.

Answer (score 1):

Not applicable to your issue. But to anyone else experiencing this behavior while on VPN, I found a closed issue in github pip repository (https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7935), where the solution was to disconnect from VPN. It helped in my case, I reconnected to VPN (I am using Tunneblick) and everything is smooth and fast again.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue. In my case it caused that I copied pip.conf file from different machine.
When I deleted this file and set all variables directly through 'pip config' command the Warnings disappeared.
Hope it helped

Answer (score -3):

I was able to install it as a su. 'sudo su' , then pip3 install sele

Comment: pip packages are not supposed to be installed as superuser