# Error while install mysqlclient in Ubuntu 20.04 (WSL)

Tags: python, mysql, django, pip, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 in WSL, using conda virtual environment with python 3.8. I need to create a django project using MySql but I have a problem installing mysqlclient.

Specifically, when I run:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

I get the following error:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f8c1955ea90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/mysqlclient/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f8c19559670>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/mysqlclient/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f8c195597c0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/mysqlclient/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f8c19559fa0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/mysqlclient/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f8c19559d90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/mysqlclient/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysqlclient==2.0.3 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mysqlclient
```

I also tried to specify a specific version of mysqlclient, but I get the same error. My network works fine.

I also tried this (from other Stackoverflow answers)

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential
```

But it didn't help.

I'm not sure what's going on so if anybody can help I would really appreciate. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Solved the problem - apparently there was some issue with pip.

Solved by running the following:

```
pip install -U pip
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential
sudo apt autoremove
```

Solution found here:
[pip install generates WARNINGS : 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at ...>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59635259/pip-install-generates-warnings-newconnectionerrorpip-vendor-urllib3-conne)